# Explain the meaning of “いくら...とはいえ”

Tags: grammar, idioms, collocations

I encounter “いくら” in combination with “とはいえ” so often that I'm fairly certain these have some kind of fixed meaning together but I can find very little about it on the internet and all I can find is in Japanese which explains the literal grammatical but since it's intended for Japanese people it doesn't really explain the nuance well.

At least, I personally would interpret segment as such as “いくら友人だとはいえ” as “Though you may very well be my friend, ” or “No matter how much you are my friend,” or something similar but I'm not sure how correct my understanding is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

From [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89/#jn-10683):

> ［副］（あとに「ても」「でも」を伴うことが多い）量や程度のはなはだしいさま。どれほど。どんなに。「―捜しても見つからない」「―子供でもわかるだろう」

So *No matter how much you are my friend* should be a literal enough translation.

For the particular case, いくら友人だとはいえ is essentially synonymous with 友人だとはいえ, possibly with more emphasis.